How to open my activity when push received and when the application is in killed state
I have been assigned a task to implement a wake-up feature for a calling application. Specifically, when the app is killed and a push notification arrives indicating an incoming call, I need to open the incoming call activity immediately.
Can anyone please guide me on how to implement this particular feature?
For now i am trying to start a foreground service with incomming call notification whe the push comes up but not able to do so.

Guys please help. If you can suggest something It will be very beneficial for me
